# Controls moving haphazardly when resizing window

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, window-resize

I have created a wpf application. The XAML code for the application is below. 
The window looks great when its run, however when I try to resize the window the controls moves haphazardly. I want the controls to stay in place like a proper windows application. Also I am new to WPF. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

I have inserted a image of original and resized window.

```
<Window x:Class="demoUI.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:demoUI"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="8*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="17*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="397*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="39*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="113*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="46*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="12*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="149*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="38*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="141*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="256*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!--<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Column="6" Height="100" Margin="9.2,13,21.6,0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>-->
        <Menu Margin="0,-4,56.2,5.8" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" >
            <MenuItem Header="File">
                <MenuItem Header="Open Log File"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Open Workspace"/>
                <Separator/>
                <MenuItem Header="Save as Workspace"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Set Path host file"/>
                <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="-34,-117,-656.4,37.6"/>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Control" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Width="60">
                <MenuItem Header="Open Command Line View"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <TextBlock Text="Connect To" Width="65" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,16.2,0,360.6" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="IP/HostName" Margin="37.8,14.2,11.4,360.6" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Line" Margin="100.8,46.2,12.4,328.6" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>

        <TextBlock Text="Protocol" Width="78" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="111.6,9,0,383.6" Grid.Column="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Row="1"/>

        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="3" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="48" Margin="2.6,0.2,0,0" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="78">
            <Button Content="Play" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="20" Margin="4.5,14.2,0,0" Width="32"/>
            <Button Content="Stop" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="20" Margin="4.5,14.2,0,0" Width="32"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="2"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="34" Margin="123.6,6.2,28.8,0" Height="115">
            <TextBlock Text="Rx" Width="20" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <CheckBox Margin="5,5,4.6,5" Height="14" />
            <CheckBox Margin="5,5,4.6,5" Height="14" RenderTransformOrigin="0.492,-0.286" />
            <CheckBox Margin="5,5,4.6,5" Height="14" />
            <CheckBox Margin="5,5,4.6,5" Height="14" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="2"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4.8,6.2,0,0" Height="124" Width="36">
            <TextBlock Text="Tx" Width="20" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            <CheckBox Margin="5,5,4.8,5" Height="14" />
            <CheckBox Margin="5,5,4.8,5" Height="14" />
            <CheckBox Margin="5,5,4.8,5" Height="14" />
            <CheckBox Margin="5,5,4.8,5" Height="14" />
        </StackPanel>


        <TextBlock Text="Log Cmd" Width="65" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="9,51.2,0,325.6" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="RSP" Margin="93.6,25.2,15.2,348.6"  Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="2" />
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="RTU" Margin="93.6,49.2,15.2,327.6" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="2" />
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Error" Margin="93.6,69.2,15.2,307.6" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="2"/>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Info" Margin="93.6,96.2,15.2,280.6" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="2" />

        <ComboBox x:Name="Job"
                  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="38.8,0,16,324.6"
                  Height="23" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Trace"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="List"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Dump"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Off"/>
        </ComboBox>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="3.6,52.2,82.2,315.6">
            <Button Content="Send" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="20" Margin="3,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="69"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I would suggest trying to find a tutorial on WPF & layout in XAML - find out what VerticalAlignment & HorizontalAlignment do - try setting them to "Top" & "Left" respectively for a start on your TextBlocks. Match up the Margins for elements that should be aligned.

Comment: @PaulF Thanks a lot. By setting the VerticalAlignment="Top"  and HorizontalAlignment="Left" my controls are not streching. However they are still scrolling. Any idea on how to make them stand at fixed position?

Comment: What do you mean by "scrolling" ? If you mean they disappear when the window gets too small - then you could set a minimum height/width to the window.. You may also consider using fixed heights rather than relative heights in your Grid RowDefinitions (remove *)

Comment: Another thing to try is giving each element a fixed Height, rather than setting to Auto. Set the third & fourth margin values to 0 for all elements. Ensure all elements have VerticalAlignment="Top".  That might fix most of the issues with elements moving or starting to disappear when you resize vertically. You will then need to play around with alignments, widths, removing column relative sizing etc for resizing horizontally. Trying things yourself is the best way to learn this in conjunction with books/tutorials on WPF/XAML layout.

Answer (score 1):

The direct cause for the wandering `TextBoxes` and `ComboBox` is that their `VerticalAlignment` is set to `Center` and they are offset back to the top of the row with the use of gigantic bottom marigins.

They are also within the third row of a `Grid`, and all of the rows' `Height` is set in a way that makes them scale to the parent container (window) size. The star '*' in `Height="8*"`, `Height="17*"` etc. results in rows filling the leftover space in their parent aiming for the specified proportions.

The main culprit behind all of this is most likely use of the designer to drag and drop everything into its place, rather than mindful utilization of the various panels/containers that are avaliable in WPF.

At the very least, you should create the initial panel setup by writing the code yourself. It will result in much cleaner and more maintainable code. I recommend using the designer only as a feedback tool in the beginning of your journey with WPF.

This is probably the layout you're looking for:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Menu Grid.Row="0">
        <MenuItem Header="File">
            <MenuItem Header="Open Log File" />
            <MenuItem Header="Open Workspace" />
            <Separator />
            <MenuItem Header="Save as Workspace" />
            <MenuItem Header="Set Path host file" />
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Control">
            <MenuItem Header="Open Command Line View" />
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    <WrapPanel Grid.Row="1" Margin="10">
        <WrapPanel.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Grid">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,20,0" />
            </Style>
        </WrapPanel.Resources>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3" />
                    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3" />
                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3" />
                    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </Grid.Resources>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Connect To" />
            <TextBox
                Grid.Column="1"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                Text="IP/HostName" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Log Cmd" />
            <ComboBox
                x:Name="Job"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="1">
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Trace" />
                <ComboBoxItem Content="List" />
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Dump" />
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Off" />
            </ComboBox>
            <TextBox
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="2"
                VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                Text="Line" />
        </Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3" />
                </Style>
            </Grid.Resources>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Content="  Play  " />
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="  Stop  " />
            <Button
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                Content="  Job  " />
        </Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3" />
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3" />
                </Style>
            </Grid.Resources>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Text="Protocol" />
            <TextBlock
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Text="Rx" />
            <TextBlock
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="2"
                Text="Tx" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="RSP" />
            <CheckBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" />
            <CheckBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" />

        </Grid>
    </WrapPanel>
</Grid>
```

Also, I would recommend reading the following article about Panels and Containers in WPF https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140613/WPF-Tutorial-Layout-Panels-Containers-Layout-Trans

Edit: Other than that I advise to **avoid** setting hard `Width` and `Height` for the containers and most of the controls. Also do not fear to nest containers into one another to achieve the desired result. It's much easier to create and work with nested containers than with a mega `Grid`.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is in your row/column definitions. By using starred values, you instruct the application to scale the width/height relative to the other columns/rows.

In other words, to make the controls stay where they are when resizing, remove the stars from the `ColumnDefinitions` / `RowDefinitions`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with my c# wpf application. All the textboxes and buttons stayed in place when I resized the window but an image kept moving around. My xaml code looked similar to this:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Margin="58,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Hello World"  Width="271" Height="28" FontSize="18"/>
    <Image Margin="5,5,735.6,372" Source="image.png" Stretch="None"/>
</Grid>
```

Here is how I fixed it:
When I clicked on the image and looked at the properties for **VerticalAlignment** and **HorizontalAlignment** in Visual Studio, they were both set to "Stretch" in the properties even though it wasn't in the xaml code. So I set both of them to "Top" and "Left". That stopped the image from moving around.

However, if I shrank the window from the bottom then a background colored box would start covering the image and if I shrank the window from the right side then the background colored box would start covering the image. To fix that I had to set the third and fourth parameters of the image **Margin** to 0. So the image Margin is now "5,5,0,0".

So here is what the final working xaml code looked like:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Margin="58,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Hello World"  Width="271" Height="28" FontSize="18"/>
    <Image Margin="5,5,0,0" Source="image.png" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Stretch="None"/>
</Grid>
```

I'm not sure why Visual Studio inserted all of the textboxes and buttons with the correct alignment and margins but it didn't do it for the image.